# Save multiple values in foreign key django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, relational-database

I wanted to save multiple relational objects in a foreign key but unfortunately, I'm getting an error which I attached below. I already have the object with ID of 189 in my DB

error:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "Invalid pk \"189\" - object does not exist."
    ]
}
```

views.py

```
queryset = PackageRoom.objects.all()
serializer = PackageRoomSerializer(queryset, many=True)    
return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class PackageRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=PackageRoom.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PackageRoom
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'tags']
```

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    singleline = models.ManyToManyField(Singleline)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tags'



class PackageRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'package_rooms'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake that I was doing there that I was passing the PackageRoom model in my serializer but I need to pass the Tag model instead.

```
class PackageRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PackageRoom
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'tags']
```